# API to add small text ads to sms's

Tags: api, sms, ads

I need a API for small text ads to include in a sms service I have developed.

But I can not find any useful info by Google. I know a lot of free sms provider add a small ad to the sms they send out.

Do there exist a service, where I can get the ads and include them, when I create the messages in C#

greetings
msdata

Answer (score 2):

See [Inuvi](http://inuvi.com). Inuvi is an SMS mobile ad network that has a real-time bidding (RTB) API designed specifically for ads that get appended to text messages.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [46elks](http://www.46elks.com) they have a simple API for sending SMS with a POST request. They also support text sender ID, hence possible for the user to see the sender with out needing to know the number.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the need for an API here and moreover I dont think there will be an API for what you are asking. You can do it yourself. Have a table with the all the advetisement texts and fetch a random record. Append it to your text message and send (?)

Comment: Maybe not random so everyone gets the same amount of texts sent :-)

Comment: I am looking for an API solely so I won't have to manage my own ads. If anyone knows of any please let me know.